# Not able to override Spring data Pageable - Spring Neo4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I need to override the Pageable class provided by spring data and then override the `findAll` method provided by the `SimpleNeo4jRepository`.

But on doing so, I am getting an error on server startup 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract com.app.backend.repository.pagination.AppPage com.app.backend.repository.BaseRepository.findAll(com.app.backend.repository.pagination.AppPageRequest)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:116) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryMethod.<init>(GraphQueryMethod.java:41) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(GraphQueryLookupStrategy.java:49) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]`

Here is the code

```
public class AppPageRequest extends PageRequest implements Pageable {

  private AppPageRequest(int page, int size, Sort sort) {
    super(page - 1, size, sort);
  }

  public static AppPageRequest of(int page, int size) {
    return of(page, size, Sort.unsorted());
  }

  public static AppPageRequest of(int page, int size, Sort sort) {
    return new AppPageRequest(page, size, sort);
  }
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Neo4jRepository<T, ID> {

  Page<T> findAll(AppPageRequest appPageRequest);
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleNeo4jRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

  public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, Session session) {
    super(domainClass, session);
  }

  public Page<T> findAll(AppPageRequest appPageRequest) {
    return super.findAll(appPageRequest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to make sure that no-one is able to call `findAll` and related with the default implementation of `Pageable`, there are two things you have to take care of:

1. You cannot override the signature of `findAll` and related by extending your `BaseRepository` from `Neo4jRepository`, the methods are not overwritten but overloaded and can be called as before.
2. To make Spring Data aware of the your custom repository implementation you have to specify the new base class when enabling Neo4j (or any other repository) (as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository)).

With that in mind, here is a solution that works for us. Tested with Spring Boot 2.0.4, Spring Data Kay and OGM 3.1.0, running on Java 10. Find the complete solution in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/michael-simons/8b37f4e07936e69c6dd33dbed4d7d780).

Keypoints:

Extend Spring Datas `CrudRepository` at max:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
    Page<T> findAll(AppPageRequest appPageRequest);
}
```

`CrudRepository` does not contain `findAll`, so your users cannot use it. Keep your `BaseRepositoryImpl` as is (see gist).

Make your domain repository extend `BaseRepository` and again not `Neo4jRepository` as such:

```
interface ThingRepository extends BaseRepository<ThingEntity, Long> {
}
```

Then the important step, make SDN aware of the new base implementation through `@EnableNeo4jRepositories`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
public class CustomPagerequestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomPagerequestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And then you're able to use your repo like this:

```
@Component
class ExampleUsage implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final ThingRepository thingRepository;

    public ExampleUsage(ThingRepository thingRepository) {
        this.thingRepository = thingRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        var things = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i <= 10, i -> i + 1)
            .mapToObj(ThingEntity::new)
            .collect(toList());
        this.thingRepository.saveAll(things);

        var page = this.thingRepository.findAll(AppPageRequest.of(1, 5));
        page.stream().map(ThingEntity::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Please let me know, if this helps. Again, here the link to the complete example:
[Enforce a concrete implementation of Pageable for paged Queries with Spring Data (Neo4j)](https://gist.github.com/michael-simons/8b37f4e07936e69c6dd33dbed4d7d780)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but for my use case I will need the methods exposed by the `Neo4jRepository` and do not want to expose those methods explicitly in the `BaseRepository`. 
From what I understood, the error was because one of the constructors of `Parameters`, `public Parameters(Method method)` and how it sets the `pageableIndex`. I have overridden this constructor to allow any subclass of `Pageable` rather than a strict match for the class.

Comment: Turns out, `repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class` configuration was missing. Adding this to the `EnableNeo4jRepositories` annotation made everything work

Comment: Cool, good to hear. As it was an explicit part of my answer (point 2) it would be kind if you’d accept my answer. Regarding exposing methods: I tend to recommend not using `Neo4jRepository` or for example `JpaRepository` but only `Repository` to keep the exposed surface of things as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It was a configuration miss. Mentioning BaseRepositoryImpl as the repository base class fixed the issue.

I changed

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
```

to

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
```